# Angular 2 initial load

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2015

I have developed my angular 2 app in visual studio 2015 (quick start), used to run my app by pressing F5. My app works perfectly fine but it takes 10 secs to load the application since all the html files in my application is downloaded in browser.

How to implement gulp and webpack (visual studio 2015) or any other method based on my folder structure, system.config.js and package.json.

Folder Structure:

[image]

```js
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "QuickStart package.json from the documentation, supplemented with testing support",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc -p src/",
    "build:watch": "tsc -p src/ -w",
    "build:e2e": "tsc -p e2e/",
    "serve": "lite-server -c=bs-config.json",
    "serve:e2e": "lite-server -c=bs-config.e2e.json",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"npm run serve\"",
    "pree2e": "npm run build:e2e",
    "e2e": "concurrently \"npm run serve:e2e\" \"npm run protractor\" --kill-others --success first",
    "preprotractor": "webdriver-manager update",
    "protractor": "protractor protractor.config.js",
    "pretest": "npm run build",
    "test": "concurrently \"npm run build:watch\" \"karma start karma.conf.js\"",
    "pretest:once": "npm run build",
    "test:once": "karma start karma.conf.js --single-run",
    "lint": "tslint ./src/**/*.ts -t verbose"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~4.1.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.1.3",
    "@angular/core": "~4.1.3",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.1.3",
    "@angular/http": "~4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.1.3",
    "@angular/router": "~4.1.3",
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.7.2",
    "angular-2-data-table": "^0.1.2",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.3.0",
    "angular2-adal": "^0.1.4",
    "angular2-csv": "^0.2.5",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.1",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "ng-editable-table": "^0.3.15",
    "ng2-accordion": "0.0.15",
    "ng2-adal": "^0.2.6",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "^0.10.4",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.6.0",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.2.2",
    "rxjs": "5.0.1",
    "systemjs": "0.20.13",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.51",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.28",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.6.0",
    "angular2-modal": "^2.0.3",
    "ng2-bs3-modal": "0.10.4",
    "ng2-accordion": "0.0.15",
    "bootstrap-daterangepicker": "^2.1.25",
    "canonical-path": "0.0.2",
    "concurrently": "^3.2.0",
    "daterange": "^0.3.0",
    "daterangepicker": "^2.1.25",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1",
    "karma": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "rimraf": "^2.5.4",
    "tslint": "^5.4.3",
    "typescript": "~2.3.4",
    "typings": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "repository": {}
}
```

```js
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': '/node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      'app': 'app',
      'directive': 'directives',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      'ng2-bs3-modal': 'npm:ng2-bs3-modal',
      "ng2-accordion": "../../node_modules/ng2-accordion",
      'angular-2-data-table': 'npm:angular-2-data-table/dist',
      'ng2-charts': 'npm:ng2-charts/bundles/ng2-charts.umd.js',
      'chart.js': 'npm:chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js',
      

      'ng2-bs3-modal': 'npm:ng2-bs3-modal',
      "ng2-accordion": "../../node_modules/ng2-accordion",
      // other libraries
      'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
      'angular2-datatable': 'npm:angular2-datatable',
      'lodash': 'npm:lodash/lodash.js',
      'ng2-adal': 'npm:ng2-adal',
      'adal': 'npm:adal-angular/lib',
      'adal-angular': 'npm:adal-angular/lib',
      'angular2-csv': 'npm:angular2-csv',
      'ng2-smart-table': 'npm:ng2-smart-table',
      'ng2-completer': 'npm:ng2-completer',

    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
        'chart.js': {defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-charts': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'jquery': { main: 'jquery.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-smart-table': { main: 'bundles/table.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-completer': { main: 'ng2-completer.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular-2-data-table': {
            format: 'cjs',
            defaultExtension: 'js',
            main: 'index.js'
        },
        'angular2-datatable': {
            main: 'index.js',
            defaultExtension: 'js'
        },
        'lodash': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-accordion': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: "js" },
        'ng2-bs3-modal': { main: 'ng2-bs3-modal.js', defaultExtension: "js" },
        'directive': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'ng2-accordion': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: "js" },
        'ng2-bs3-modal': { main: 'ng2-bs3-modal.js', defaultExtension: "js" },
        'ng2-adal': { main: 'core.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'adal-angular': { main: 'adal-angular', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'adal': { main: 'adal.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-csv': { main: 'Angular2-csv', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        //'ng2-daterangepicker': {
        //    main: 'index',
        //    defaultExtension: 'js'
        //},
        //moment: {
        //    main: 'moment',
        //    defaultExtension: 'js'
        //},
      app: {
        defaultExtension: 'js',
        meta: {
          './*.js': {
            loader: 'systemjs-angular-loader.js'
          }
        }
      },
      'rxjs': {
        main: 'Rx.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <base href="/src/">
      <!--<base href="/">-->
      <title>BostonPizza-Dashboard</title>   
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge,chrome=1'><![endif]-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">-->
      
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
      <link href="assets/plugins/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/plugins/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/plugins/css/sumoselect.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/plugins/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/plugins/css/itcavant.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/plugins/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/plugins/css/simple-line-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/plugins/css/daterangepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    
      <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES -->
     
      <!-- BEGIN THEME LAYOUT STYLES  -->
      <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/css/bptheme.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="assets/css/mediaquery.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- END THEME LAYOUT STYLES  -->
      <!-- BEGIN OLD IE BROWSER -->
      <!--[ifltIE9]>
    <scriptsrc="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
    <scriptsrc="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
      <!-- END OLD IE BROWSER -->

      
      
     

    <!-- Polyfill(s) for older browsers -->
    <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
      
     

      <!-- BEGIN CORE PLUGINS -->
      <script src="assets/plugins/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      
      <script src="assets/plugins/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="assets/plugins/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="assets/plugins/js/jquery.sumoselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="assets/plugins/js/moment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>     
      <script src="assets/plugins/js/daterangepicker.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {

              
              

              $(window).scroll(function () {
                  set = $(document).scrollTop() + "px";
                  $('#floatdiv').animate({
                      top: set
                  }, {
                      duration: 500,
                      queue: false
                  });
              });



          });
          
          function openNav() {
          
                  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "200px";
                  document.getElementById("overlayblock").style.width = "100%";
                  document.getElementById("overlayblock").style.opacity = "0.8";
                 
                  
                  
              }

             
             
          function closeNav() {
              
                  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
                  document.getElementById("overlayblock").style.width = "0%";
                  document.getElementById("overlayblock").style.opacity = "0";
                  
                  
              }
             
              /*******************************
               * ACCORDION WITH TOGGLE ICONS
               *******************************/
              function toggleIcon(e) {
                  $(e.target)
                      .prev('.panel-heading')
                      .find(".more-less")
                      .toggleClass('icon-arrow-up icon-arrow-down');
              }
              $('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
              $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);


      </script>
      <!-- END CORE PLUGINS -->

    <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('main.js').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });        
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <my-app><!--Loading AppComponent content here ...-->
        
    <div class="loadingbg"><img src="assets/images/BP_logo.png" class="img-responsive main_bg" /></div>  
    </my-app>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this a duplicate of the question you asked earlier? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49242510/angular-2-using-visual-studio-2015

Comment: Have you looked into using the Angular CLI to build instead of using that quick start? It comes with webpack bundling built into it. I would recommend you start there to abstract away all of this stuff. http://cli.angular.io

Comment: @Daniel...Included all the files package.json , system.config.js and index.html

Comment: You should have updated the other one with all of these details and not created a new question.

Comment: @Daniel..I have already developed my app and it is in production and its hightime converting to Angular CLI. I tried converting  to angular cli but was getting lots of exceptions since i was using system.config.js and vs 2015.

Comment: VS 2015 won't be the reason you had problems with the Angular CLI. I have multiple projects on VS 2015/2017 that are using it. You won't need all of the system.config.js stuff if you use the CLI. It's up to you if you want to switch over, I'm just recommending you do.

Comment: The Angular quick start is deprecated now and you'll see this message: "This repository is now deprecated. The Angular Quickstart project was a nice starting point for creating Angular applications. Now we recommend using the Angular CLI to create new Angular projects." https://github.com/angular/quickstart

Comment: I like to convert my project to CLI but i am not able to convert those. angular 2 datatatable was not working after convrsion and had few more issues like this.Apart from CLI will u able to help me in improving the performance stuff..like y all html files are downloading in initial.

Comment: We had similar performance issues previously and it is part of the reason we switched over. The Angular team put a ton of optimizations into the build process to fix a bunch of issues like what you are talking about.